# Windows forms - C++/CLR (.NET Framework) - How to use button events

Tags: c++, .net, opencv, events, clr

I am building an application that uses Computer Vision to detect objects with a webcam.

1. To implement the idea, I use the OpenCV library and C++.
2. To build the windows form I am using C++/CLR (.NET Framework) with Visual Studio 2019.

I have already got the program to work but I want to improve my code.

**Introduction to my question:** 
I want to make less and more efficient code in the "button events" which you can see in "CODE 1". The reason for it, is because I am almost using the same code for all of the three buttons (it takes a lot of space and is ugly).

My idea is to build a class around the code which you can see in the button events and make instances of the class in each button event. The problem is, I also need to be able to press the exit button and control the member variables I have in CODE 1.

The three private member variables in CODE 1 are as follows:

```
    //// private member variables
    private:
        bool CamWhileLoop1;
        bool CamWhileLoop2;
        bool CamWhileLoop3;
```

I use them to turn the while loops on and off in each button event so the webcam window will be turned off when a new event is pressed.

(the webcam window is provided by the OpenCV library when you press one of the three buttons).

**My questions:**

1. What is the best and most efficient way to implement this.
2. Is it good as it is?
3. I am using already trained Haar Cascade files from the OpenCV library to detect the objects. My program is very slow and the webcam lags a lot. How can get rid of this lag? (I think I need to use YOLO or some other implementation of the Artificial Intelligence (AI) part but i'm not sure)
4. Is it good as it is? Do I need to turn one event off by my self when another button event is pressed or does that happen automatically inside of the C++/CLR library?

CODE 1 and CODE 2 are found below.

[image]

**CODE 1: Here is my "windows Form code" called MyForm.h**

```
#pragma once

// Include OpenCV
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
// Include C++ libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

//#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


namespace ObjectCounter {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    
    protected:

    //// private member variables
    private:
        bool CamWhileLoop1;
        bool CamWhileLoop2;
        bool CamWhileLoop3;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button4;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(113, 64);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(459, 65);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"Count Faces";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 20, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(83, 422);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(297, 39);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label1->Text = L"Amount of objects:";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 30, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(477, 403);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(53, 58);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label2->Text = L"0";
            this->label2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label2_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(113, 135);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(459, 65);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 3;
            this->button2->Text = L"Count Eyes";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(113, 206);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(459, 65);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button3->Text = L"Count Russian License Plates";
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button3_Click);
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(240, 301);
            this->button4->Name = L"button4";
            this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(214, 39);
            this->button4->TabIndex = 5;
            this->button4->Text = L"Exit";
            this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button4->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button4_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(680, 560);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"Artificial Intelligence Counter";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion


    private: System::Void label2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }


    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) { // Count Faces
        //Initialize variables
        unsigned int ObjectCounter1 = 0;
        this->CamWhileLoop1 = true;
        this->CamWhileLoop2 = false;
        this->CamWhileLoop3 = false;


        cv::VideoCapture Video_Capture1(0); // Create an instance of the cv::VideoCapture class
        cv::Mat image1;                     // Create an instance of the cv:Mat class (creating an empty image)
        cv::CascadeClassifier faceCascade1; // Create an instance of the cv::CascadeClassifier class
        faceCascade1.load("Resources/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"); // Load haar cascade file

        if (!Video_Capture1.isOpened()) {   // Check if camera opened successfully
            std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
            //return -1;
        }

        if (faceCascade1.empty()) {         // Check if the XML file has been loaded properly or not
            std::cout << "XML file not loaded." << std::endl;
        }

        std::vector<cv::Rect> Rectangles_for_objects1;  // Storing rectangles in a vector 

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200)); //Giving the webcam time to start

        while (this->CamWhileLoop1) {
            Video_Capture1.read(image1);    //Create matrix from the webcam
            faceCascade1.detectMultiScale(image1, Rectangles_for_objects1, 1.1, 10);

            for (int i = 0; i < Rectangles_for_objects1.size(); i++) {  // Iterate over all objects and print them
                //Code for rectangle around faces
                cv::rectangle(image1, Rectangles_for_objects1[i].tl(), Rectangles_for_objects1[i].br(), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);
                //tl = top left and br = bottom right
            }
            
            // For the counter part
            if (Rectangles_for_objects1.size() != ObjectCounter1) {
                if (Rectangles_for_objects1.size() == 0) {
                    std::cout << "There is no person in the image" << std::endl;
                }
                else if (Rectangles_for_objects1.size() == 1) {
                    std::cout << "There is " << Rectangles_for_objects1.size() << " person in the image" << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "There are " << Rectangles_for_objects1.size() << " persons in the image" << std::endl;
                }
                ObjectCounter1 = Rectangles_for_objects1.size();
                label2->Text = ObjectCounter1.ToString();
            }
            cv::imshow("Video", image1);
            cv::waitKey(1);

        }
        //Show the image in a window. name of the window="Video". The Image to be shown= img (p.209)

    }
    
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    //Initialize variables
    unsigned int ObjectCounter2 = 0;
    this->CamWhileLoop1 = false;
    this->CamWhileLoop2 = true;
    this->CamWhileLoop3 = false;

    cv::VideoCapture Video_Capture2(0); // Create an instance of the cv::VideoCapture class
    cv::Mat image2;                     // Create an instance of the cv:Mat class (creating an empty image)
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceCascade2; // Create an instance of the cv::CascadeClassifier class
    faceCascade2.load("Resources/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml"); // Load haar cascade file

    if (!Video_Capture2.isOpened()) {   // Check if camera opened successfully
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        //return -1;
    }

    if (faceCascade2.empty()) {         // Check if the XML file has been loaded properly or not
        std::cout << "XML file not loaded." << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<cv::Rect> Rectangles_for_objects2;  // Storing rectangles in a vector 

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200)); //Giving the webcam time to start

    while (this->CamWhileLoop2) {
        Video_Capture2.read(image2);
        faceCascade2.detectMultiScale(image2, Rectangles_for_objects2, 1.1, 10);

        //if(Main_Window.textBox1->Text )

        for (int i = 0; i < Rectangles_for_objects2.size(); i++) {  // Iterate over all objects and print them
            //Code for rectangle around faces
            cv::rectangle(image2, Rectangles_for_objects2[i].tl(), Rectangles_for_objects2[i].br(), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);
            //tl = top left
            //br = bottom right
        }

        // For the counter part
        if (Rectangles_for_objects2.size() != ObjectCounter2) {
            if (Rectangles_for_objects2.size() == 0) {
                std::cout << "There is no person in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            else if (Rectangles_for_objects2.size() == 1) {
                std::cout << "There is " << Rectangles_for_objects2.size() << " person in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "There are " << Rectangles_for_objects2.size() << " persons in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            ObjectCounter2 = Rectangles_for_objects2.size();
            label2->Text = ObjectCounter2.ToString();
        }

        //Show the image in a window. name of the window="Video". The Image to be shown= img (p.209)
        cv::imshow("Video", image2);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
}
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    //Initialize variables
    unsigned int ObjectCounter3 = 0;
    this->CamWhileLoop1 = false;
    this->CamWhileLoop2 = false;
    this->CamWhileLoop3 = true;


    cv::VideoCapture Video_Capture(0);  // Create an instance of the cv::VideoCapture class
    cv::Mat image;                      // Create an instance of the cv:Mat class (creating an empty image)
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceCascade;  // Create an instance of the cv::CascadeClassifier class
    faceCascade.load("Resources/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml"); // Load haar cascade file

    if (!Video_Capture.isOpened()) {    // Check if camera opened successfully
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        //return -1;
    }

    if (faceCascade.empty()) {          // Check if the XML file has been loaded properly or not
        std::cout << "XML file not loaded." << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<cv::Rect> Rectangles_for_objects;   // Storing rectangles in a vector 

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200)); //Giving the webcam time to start

    while (this->CamWhileLoop3) {
        Video_Capture.read(image);
        faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image, Rectangles_for_objects, 1.1, 10);

        //if(Main_Window.textBox1->Text )

        for (int i = 0; i < Rectangles_for_objects.size(); i++) {   // Iterate over all objects and print them
            //Code for rectangle around faces
            cv::rectangle(image, Rectangles_for_objects[i].tl(), Rectangles_for_objects[i].br(), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);
            //tl = top left
            //br = bottom right
        }

        // For the counter part
        if (Rectangles_for_objects.size() != ObjectCounter3) {
            if (Rectangles_for_objects.size() == 0) {
                std::cout << "There is no person in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            else if (Rectangles_for_objects.size() == 1) {
                std::cout << "There is " << Rectangles_for_objects.size() << " person in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "There are " << Rectangles_for_objects.size() << " persons in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            ObjectCounter3 = Rectangles_for_objects.size();
            label2->Text = ObjectCounter3.ToString();
        }

        //Show the image in a window. name of the window="Video". The Image to be shown= img (p.209)
        cv::imshow("Video", image);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
}
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->CamWhileLoop1 = false;
    this->CamWhileLoop2 = false;
    this->CamWhileLoop3 = false;

    this->Close();
}
};
}
```

**CODE 2: Here is my "Source code" called Source.cpp**

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace ObjectCounter;
[STAThreadAttribute]

int main()
{
    MyForm MainWindow;
    MainWindow.ShowDialog();

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for reading the question!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all three button click routines are identical except for the cascade XML file used.  And the video camera only allows a single instance to run at a time, so create a single routine to perform the common functionality for each button:

```
private: System::Void RunCascadeClassifier(string xmlName) {
    //Initialize variables
    unsigned int ObjectCounter1 = 0;
    this->CamWhileLoop1 = true;

    cv::VideoCapture Video_Capture1(0); // Create an instance of the cv::VideoCapture class
    cv::Mat image1;                     // Create an instance of the cv:Mat class (creating an empty image)
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceCascade1; // Create an instance of the cv::CascadeClassifier class
    faceCascade1.load(xmlName); // Load haar cascade file

    if (!Video_Capture1.isOpened()) {   // Check if camera opened successfully
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        //return -1;
    }

    if (faceCascade1.empty()) {         // Check if the XML file has been loaded properly or not
        std::cout << "XML file not loaded." << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<cv::Rect> Rectangles_for_objects1;  // Storing rectangles in a vector 

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200)); //Giving the webcam time to start

    while (this->CamWhileLoop1) {
        Video_Capture1.read(image1);    //Create matrix from the webcam
        faceCascade1.detectMultiScale(image1, Rectangles_for_objects1, 1.1, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < Rectangles_for_objects1.size(); i++) {  // Iterate over all objects and print them
            //Code for rectangle around faces
            cv::rectangle(image1, Rectangles_for_objects1[i].tl(), Rectangles_for_objects1[i].br(), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);
            //tl = top left and br = bottom right
        }
        
        // For the counter part
        if (Rectangles_for_objects1.size() != ObjectCounter1) {
            if (Rectangles_for_objects1.size() == 0) {
                std::cout << "There is no person in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            else if (Rectangles_for_objects1.size() == 1) {
                std::cout << "There is " << Rectangles_for_objects1.size() << " person in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "There are " << Rectangles_for_objects1.size() << " persons in the image" << std::endl;
            }
            ObjectCounter1 = Rectangles_for_objects1.size();
            label2->Text = ObjectCounter1.ToString();
        }
        cv::imshow("Video", image1);
        cv::waitKey(1);

    }
    //Show the image in a window. name of the window="Video". The Image to be shown= img (p.209)
}
```

and then call this from each button click:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this.RunCascadeClassifier("Resources/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
}
```

and your exit button is just:

```
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->CamWhileLoop1 = false;
    this->Close();
}
```